# Dynamically picking variable from a class

Tags: php, class, variables, this

I'm trying to get data from a class in php5, where the data in the class is private and the calling function is requesting a piece of data from the class.  I want to be able to gain that specific piece of data from the private variables without using a case statement.

I want to do something to the effect of:

```
public function get_data($field)
{
    return $this->(variable with name passed in $field, i.e. name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use

```
class Muffin
{
   private $_colour = 'red';

   public function get_data($field)
   {
      return $this->$field;
   }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
$a = new Muffin();

var_dump($a->get_data('_colour'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
public function get_data($field)
{
    return $this->{$field};
}
?>
```

You may want to look at the magical __get() function too, e.g.:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
        private $prop = 'bar';
        public function __get($key)
        {
                return $this->{$key};
        }
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->prop;
?>
```

I would be careful with this kind of code, as it may allow too much of the class's internal data to be exposed.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into __get as well.